# Commenting multiple lines in Vscode with Neovim extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim, neovim-plugin

I'm happily using Vscode with the Neovim extension except for one issue: I haven't found a way to comment/uncomment multiple lines of code without visually selecting them first and using cmd-/.

I've tried all Neovim commenting plugins I could find with no success.
I'd simply like to type something like 5gcc to comment/uncomment 5 lines.

Any idea?